# How to I get an image to show a certain amount of times for Val in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

This question in HTML asks for the user to enter a number 1-5 and then it will show the amount of numbers entered as a picture of a dice with question marks on them. No matter what number I put in I will always get 6 dice to show with question marks. How do I fix this?

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
      <style>
        body {
          text-align: center;
        }
        
        img {
          height: 150px;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <h1>Click the button to see the roll of a die randomly selected</h1>
      <script>
        Val = window.prompt("Enter the number of dice to play with (1-5)");
        <!--if user enters a number <= 1 val ==1-->
        if(Val == 1 || Val <= 1){
          Val = 1;
        }
        else if(Val == 2){
          Val = 2;
        }
        else if(Val == 3){
          Val = 3;
        }
        else if(Val == 4){
          Val = 4;
        }
        <!--if user enters anything thats not 1-4 val = 5-->
        else Val = 5;
        function roll() {
          var randomDie = Math.floor(Val*Math.random()) + 1;
          var RandomNum = Math.floor(6*Math.random()) + 1;
          document.getElementById('dieImg' + randomDie).setAttribute("src","dieImages/die" + RandomNum + ".jpg");
          document.getElementById('dieImg' + randomDie).style.display="inline";
          document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = "Die " + randomDie + " was selected and rolled to show " + RandomNum;
        }
      </script>
      <!--Show question mark die-->
      <img id="dieImg1" src="dieImages/question-mark-dice.jpg">
      <img id="dieImg2" src="dieImages/question-mark-dice.jpg">
      <img id="dieImg3" src="dieImages/question-mark-dice.jpg">
      <img id="dieImg4" src="dieImages/question-mark-dice.jpg">
      <img id="dieImg5" src="dieImages/question-mark-dice.jpg">
      <hr>
      <button type="button" onclick="roll()">Click to Roll</button>
      <p id="display">--</p>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

This is what the application shows when I put in 3,
[image: screenshot image]

This is what I want the output to be,
[image: screenshot image]

Comment: Welcome to the community Aaron. There is no need to be explicit with `if ... else if ... else ...` when the logic is obvious. KayD demonstrated it well below in his answer. Also, you need to understand that HTML is not dynamic by itself, javascript (or CSS) make it dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

#### First of all you do not need to re-assign every value

```js
    if(Val == 1 || Val <= 1){
      Val = 1;
    }
    else if(Val == 2){
      Val = 2;
    }
    else if(Val == 3){
      Val = 3;
    }
    else if(Val == 4){
      Val = 4;
    }
```

this works same as above

```js
//if user enters a number <= 1 val ==1
if (Val < 1) {
  Val = 1;
}
//if user enters anything thats not 1-4 val = 5
if (Val > 4) {
  Val = 5
}
```

#### Second,

it's showing the 5 images everytime because you have mentioned that in the HTML, you need to create the img element dynamically using `createElement` using a loop.

```js
 let img = document.createElement('img');
 img.src = "dieImages/question-mark-dice.jpg";
 img.id = "dieImg" + i;
 let dices = document.getElementById("dices");
 dices.appendChild(img);
```

#### I re-wrote your example, which is working as you are expecting.

---

```js
Val = window.prompt("Enter the number of dice to play with (1-5)");

//if user enters a number <= 1 val ==1
if (Val < 1) {
  Val = 1;
}
//if user enters anything thats not 1-4 val = 5
if (Val > 4) {
  Val = 5
}
for (i = 1; i <= Val; i++) {
  let img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = "dieImages/question-mark-dice.jpg";
  img.id = "dieImg" + i;
  let dices = document.getElementById("dices");
  dices.appendChild(img);
}

function roll() {
  var randomDie = Math.floor(Val * Math.random()) + 1;
  var RandomNum = Math.floor(6 * Math.random()) + 1;
  var diceElement = document.getElementById('dieImg' + randomDie);
  diceElement.setAttribute("src", "dieImages/die" + RandomNum + ".jpg");
  diceElement.style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = "Die " + randomDie + " was selected and rolled to show " + RandomNum;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    body {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    img {
      height: 150px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Click the button to see the roll of a die randomly selected</h1>
  <!--Show question mark die-->
  <div id="dices">
  </div>
  <hr>
  <button type="button" onclick="roll()">Click to Roll</button>
  <p id="display">--</p>
</body>

</html>
```